# How to find tuple counts in a list using a "type" function?

Tags: python, for-loop

For a list of elements with various classes, how can I count the number of tuple elements by using a 'type' function?

For instance, I have a list as follows:

List = [1.2, 'a', (2, 4.2), 3, (6, 'm')]

Comment: `sum(isinstance(i, tuple) for i in List)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this code:

```
List = [1.2, 'a', (2, 4.2), 3, (6, 'm')]
Tuple = 0

for i in List:
    if type(i) == tuple :
        Tuple += 1

print(Tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Comment from @deceze is definitely sleeker, but leaving this for a more step by step approach.

you can use the [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function, to determine, if an element of your list is a tuple, and then just count it.

```
count = 0
for elem in List:
    if isinstance(elem, tuple):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: better to switch to what @deceze suggested in the comment, more pythonic and super crisp!

Comment: Thanks warmly. isinstance is an awesome func. however, I had to do this coding with "type" func.

Comment: Then you can use the adapted @deceze answer with
`sum((type(i) == tuple) for i in List)`